# Silverlight set cursor to Cursors.Wait

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight

I have a silverlight application. When some action is executed, i want to show a wait cursor.

The problem is that i'm working with threads, and all my actions are executed in a thread.

So i have a threading helper that invokes and awaits all the threads - this works fine.

**I need to access the main window element to change its cursor. How can i achieve this?**

This:

```
ThreadingHelper.Invoke(() => App.Current.MainWindow.Content.Cursor = cursorStyle);
```

Throws me System.NotSupportedException: Out-of-browser specific settings do not affect in-browser applications.

How can i do the same for In-browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working by this code:

```
ThreadingHelper.Invoke(() => {
                        var page = (MainPage)Application.Current.RootVisual;
                        page.Cursor = cursorStyle;
                    });
```

But maybe someone will offer more type-safe method?